# Rich Grid (grouping, sorting, paging, etc) that work on ie6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, extjs, grid

I m looking for a feature rich grid ( sorting, grouping, paging , ideally filtering, etc) grid that will work well under ie6. 
I would prefer it to be an open source solution with a big community. However the client experience is the priority. 
The most obvious contender so far is **ExtJs** or **GXT**.

I have a .net serverside , quite possibly Asp.Net MVC 
I had a look at jQuery and Flexigrid and jqQuery are definitely runners but I don't seem to have grouping and movable columns in the component. I do wonder how hard it is to extend the component while still updatable 
I m also looking at Components libraries ( such as DevExpress and Telerik), not really my wish but they do seem to offer a very rich feature set.

Silverlight or anything that needs an install is totally out of scope

Any ideas? Where you evaluating grids recently and have a comment?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext supports all of your requirements.  This isn't really a question anyone can answer for you  -- you really need to try it out for yourself and see if it fits your needs.  There are lots of Ext grid sample pages to get you started.

The server-side components you mentioned should work fine too if that's your model, but that's a totally different development paradigm than a client side component like the Ext grid.  If you are doing pure .NET MVC then those may not be your best option.

Comment: I was trying to find other alternatives but thanks for your answer